# why is php not looking for names along the namespace hierarchy

Tags: php, namespaces, theory

```
<?php
namespace App {
    function date(...$args) { echo 'Wow, my date'; }    
    class A {};
}

namespace App\Core {
    echo date('r'); // Thu, 30 Mar 2023 07:34:30 +0000
    $a = new A;     // Class 'App\\Core\\A' not found
}
```

But i would like to see 'Wow, my date' :)

I know that's how it works. But I'm wondering why the namespace doesn't support hierarchy? Is this just an implementation feature or a fundamental limitation?

php was used just as an example. From other hand,  this happens when the namespace is implicitly declared in functions and loops in many programming languages.
But what reason stops languages developers from using hierarchical search?

Comment: The code above doesn't define class App\Core\A, only App\A.  Not sure what you're expecting - please can you clarify?

Comment: Pretty sure namespaces weren't defined keeping hierarchy in mind. So it's a fundamental limitation.

Comment: Why **should** it do that? Is that defined anywhere?

Comment: @NicoHaase I find it inconvenient that it doesn't do that. But it is so. And I asked if anyone knows why. Else, for example, a function could be overwritten for an application by define it in \App namespace

Comment: @nice_dev but this happens when the namespace is implicitly declared in functions and loops in many programming languages

Comment: Please do not edit questions in a way that invalidates existing answers. You asked about PHP and someone answered about PHP; your question is now and forevermore about PHP.

Answer (score 0):

With PHP, you can only access the global scope of a hierarchy.

> https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php

The global namespace is declared using the empty identifier.

```
namespace {class A {};}
```

and so this works

```
<?php

namespace {class A {};}

namespace App {
    function date(...$args) { echo 'Wow, my date'; }    
    class A {};
}

namespace App\Core {
    echo date('r'); // Thu, 30 Mar 2023 07:34:30 +0000
    $a = new \A;
}

?>
```

where `$a = new \A` looks for A in the global scope.

Comment: this link is, seems, closer https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.fallback.php . I understand how it works. But it does not answer the question  what reason stop languages developers from using hierarchical search

Comment: @splash58; you can only go forwards:`<?php

namespace App\Crust {
    function e() {echo 'crust'.date('r');}
}
namespace App\Core {
    function e() {echo 'core'.date('r'); } 
}
namespace App {Crust\e();Core\e();}
?>`

Comment: of course I can explicitly specify \App\date() to make it work.But i need to know at what level of hierarchy this function is declared.